# C# Mapping a list to numbered variables

Tags: c#, list, mapping

Yes, I'm well aware **Not** to do this, but I have no choice. I'd agree that it's an XYZ issue, but since I can't update the service I *have* to use, it's out of my hands. I need some help to save some time, maybe learn something handy in the process.

I'm looking to map a list of models (items in this example) to what is essentially numbered variables of a service I'm posting to, in the example, that's the fields a part of new 'newUser'.

Additionally, there may not be always be X amount items in the list (On the right in the example), and yet I have a finite amount (say 10) of numbered variables from 'newUser' to map to (On the left in the example). So I'll have to perform a bunch of checks to avoid indexing a null value as well.

Current example:

```
if (items.Count >= 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[0].id))
{
    newUser.itemId1 = items[0].id;
    newUser.itemName1 = items[0].name;
    newUser.itemDate1 = items[0].date;
    newUser.itemBlah1 = items[0].blah;
}
else
{
    // This isn't necessary, but this effectively what will happen
    newUser.itemId1 = string.Empty;
    newUser.itemName1 = string.Empty;
    newUser.itemDate1 = string.Empty;
    newUser.itemBlah1 = string.Empty;
}


if (items.Count >= 2 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[1].id))
{
    newUser.itemId2 = items[1].id;
    newUser.itemName2 = items[1].name;
    newUser.itemDate2 = items[1].date;
    newUser.itemBlah2 = items[1].blah;
}

// Removed the else to clean it up, but you get the idea.
// And so on, repeated many more times..
```

I looked into an example using Dictionary, but I'm unsure of how to map that to the model without just manually mapping all the variables.

PS: To all who come across this question, if you're implementing numbered variables in your API, please don't- it's wildly unnecessary and time consuming.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean there's another object called `newUser.itemId2`?

Comment: Yes, and itemId3, and itemId4, and so on. Sorry, let me update the question to hopefully make that bit clearer.

Comment: And to clarify, is the generating of the `newUser` model purely for POSTing to another service? An avenue that could be pursued is to build this request model as a JSON represented string and pass that along as `StringContent`

Comment: Oooo that's not actually a bad idea at all. The rest of the model is quite large, but I don't see why I couldn't just append/ replace those fields with some build up strings to the already generated JSON, I'll have to look into that. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: you could probably write a custom json serialiser to perform the translation instead, so that `item[1].name => itemname1`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to fiddling with the JSON, you could get down and dirty and use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).

Given the following test data:

```
const int maxItemsToSend = 3;
class ItemToSend {
    public string
        itemId1, itemName1,
        itemId2, itemName2,
        itemId3, itemName3;
}
ItemToSend newUser = new();

record Item(string id, string name);
Item[] items = { new("1", "A"), new("2", "B") };
```

Using the rules you set forth in the question, we can loop through the projected fields as so:

```
// If `itemid1`,`itemId2`, etc are fields:
var fields = typeof(ItemToSend).GetFields();
// If they're properties, replace GetFields() with 
// .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

for(var i = 1; i <= maxItemsToSend; i++){
    // bounds check
    var item = (items.Count() >= i && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[i-1].id))
        ? items[i-1] : null;
    
    // Use Reflection to find and set the fields
    fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals($"itemId{i}"))
        ?.SetValue(newUser, item?.id ?? string.Empty);

    fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals($"itemName{i}"))
        ?.SetValue(newUser, item?.name ?? string.Empty);
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works. Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AHHW3o).